# JQuery Draggable / Droppable - changing clone to a new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I have created a website where the users can pull widgets from a pop up modal onto the main drop zone and create widgets. Initially, the widgets are just images eg: BBC. When dragged onto the droppable area they become widgets that pull in information from an API. I have set up location saving using local storage so that when the user refreshes the page, the widgets stay in their location.

> The problem I am having, is that the widget will not save its location
>   until the user has refreshed once, then it will continue to save from
>   here

I think I know why, i just don't know how to fix it! See info below on what I have gathered.

**My code for drag and drop:**

```
$(function () {
        $("#techcrunch").draggable({ revert: 'invalid', helper:"clone",
        containment:"#dropZonetc",snap: '#dropZonetc',addClasses: false});
        $( "#dropZonetc" ).droppable({

            accept: '#techcrunch',
            activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
            hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                var offset = ui.helper.offset();
                var dropElem = ui.helper.clone()
                $(dropElem).html("<div id='techcrunchwidget' class='widgets'><img src='http://i.newsapi.org/techcrunch-s.png' alt='Tech Crunch' height='22' width='100'><button class='closewidget' onclick='destroytechcrunch()'>X</button><div class='techCrunchContent'><ul id='techcontent'></ul><script>retrieveTechCrunchNews();</script></div></div>");
                dropElem.appendTo( this ).offset( offset ).hide().fadeIn(1500);
                localStorage.setItem("techcrunch", "true");
                $( "#techcrunch" ).remove();
                $("div.widgets").draggable();
            }
        });
    });
```

**My code for saving the location:**

```
$(function () {


        var widget3 = $("#techcrunchwidget");

        updatePosition3(widget3);

        widget3.draggable({ stop: function () {

            var left = this.offsetLeft;
            var top = this.offsetTop;

            console.log(left);
            console.log(top);
            localStorage.setItem("lefttech", left);
            localStorage.setItem("toptech", top);
            $("div.widgets").draggable();   

        }
        });

        window.addEventListener("storage", function (e) {
            updatePosition3(widget3);
        }, 

        false);


    });

        function updatePosition3(widget3) {

            var left = localStorage.getItem("lefttech");
            var top = localStorage.getItem("toptech") - 20;
            widget3.css({ left: left + "px", top: top + "px" });
            widget3[0].offsetTop = top;
            widget3[0].offsetLeft = left
        }
```

**

> I am 80% sure it is because I am appending the dropElem which is a
>   clone, therefore the save script is not finding the "techcrunchwidget"
>   as it is the clone until refresh, this can be seen in the image below

**

[Chrome Element Inspecter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNLhZ.png)

Once refreshed, it is not wrapped in that wierd class.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please include some of your HTML. I suspect that you're cloning the helper element `div`, so it's there before the refresh, but not after since the element is built without the `div`. Suspect you want to build a new widget and not clone the helper.

Answer (score 1):

I would try simply append the new HTML in drop and just remove the helper.

```
drop: function( event, ui ) {
  var offset = ui.helper.offset();
  var $widget = $("<div id='techcrunchwidget' class='widgets'><img src='http://i.newsapi.org/techcrunch-s.png' alt='Tech Crunch' height='22' width='100'><button class='closewidget' onclick='destroytechcrunch()'>X</button><div class='techCrunchContent'><ul id='techcontent'></ul><script>retrieveTechCrunchNews();</script></div></div>");
  $widget.appendTo(this).offset(offset).hide().fadeIn(1500);
  localStorage.setItem("techcrunch", "true");
  ui.helper.remove();
  $("#techcrunch").remove();
  $("div.widgets").draggable();
}
```

Untested solution.

Comment: okay, that solves the clone problem! however it still doesn't save the position until after one refresh. My html doesn't have any link to this as the widgets all get added dynamically. Im really confused as to what could be the problem. I have even tried storing the location after dropping, just after appending

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I'm not sure what you're referring to since your post is lacking a more complete example.